# UrlEncode/System.Web not available in console application?

Tags: .net, reference, urlencode

I need [UrlEncode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t.aspx) in my application because i am submitting a form to my server. My app is a quick console utility targeting to .NET 3.5.

The page says i need System.Web assembly, yet when i try to add the reference it isnt there. My WebServer application has it which is also targeted to 3.5 but this console app cant reference it. Why not? how can i access UrlEncode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can - just make sure you've added a reference to System.Web.dll, which may not be in a console project by default.

I suspect this isn't in the Client Profile, mind you - I don't know if that's an issue for you.

I've just tested this with a console app from the command line:

```
using System;
using System.Web;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "hello there";
        string encoded = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(text);
        Console.WriteLine(encoded); // prints hello+there
    }
}
```

I was able to just compile with

```
csc Test.cs
```

but I suspect the default response file contains more assembly references than the default Console Application project template in Visual Studio...

Comment: Thats the thing, i do see System.Web.* but not system.web. Here is an image http://i30.tinypic.com/jt1e80.jpg As you can see it is .NET 3.5 but not client profile. -edit- note i am using System.Web.Extension for json reasons

Comment: I browsed to the full path (`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\System.Web.dll`) and it worked fine. Weird that it doesnt show in the default add reference window.

Comment: @acidzombie24: That's thoroughly weird. System.Web certainly *should* be available... it is for me, in VS2008. Checking C# Express 2010 now...

Comment: Were you definitely sorting by Component Name? There's no sort order indicator in your picture. Remove the reference and give it another go :)

Comment: Ah, that was the problem. It WASNT sorted by name. I thought it would be by default and it seemed to be. Visual Studios 2010 Ultimate.